# Add sub-namespace(s) to all classes in the project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have created classes under the `Company` root namespace. Now, I want to add to all classes the `Product` sub-namespace so that all classes are under the `Company.Product` root namespace. I use Visual Studio 2015. Is  there anyway to achieve that automatically? I have tried to rename the namespace, but it does not allow include dots in the name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit -> Find & Replace -> Replace in Files -> Replace "namespace Company" with "namespace Company.Product".

Although I tried the rename feature (right click the namespace and rename) in VS 2013 and it worked also.